# Return key-value pair instead of nodes in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I'm using the following GraphQL query to fetch project information from Gitlab:

```json
{
          projects(ids: [gid://gitlab/Project/476]) {
              nodes {
                id,
                name,
                ciVariables {
                    nodes {
                      key,
                      value
                    }
                }
              }
          }
        }
```

Everything looks fine, except the `ciVariables` part. What I get is the following:

```json
      "projects": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "id": "gid://gitlab/Project/476",
            "name": "myproject",
            "ciVariables": {
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "key": "key1",
                  "value": "value1"
                },
                {
                  "key": "key2",
                  "value": "value2"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

But what I want is this:

```json
      "projects": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "id": "gid://gitlab/Project/476",
            "name": "myproject",
            "ciVariables": {
              "key1": "value1",
              "key2": "value2"
            }
          }
        }
```

Is this possible with GraphQL to return this structure and if so, how to do that?

Comment: If the schema supports it, you can, but if the schema doesn't, there's no way in GraphQL to transform the data like this.  (You could of course rearrange it on the client side.)

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze How can I check if it's supported or what do I need to add to my query to give it a try?

Comment: Most interactive GraphQL tools have a way to introspect the schema.  What type is `ciVariables { node }`, and does that type have a field `key1`?

Comment: @DavidMaze When I query the type "CiVariable" (which every `node` is implementing) using `{
  __type(name: "CiVariable") {
    name,
    fields {
      description
      deprecationReason
    }
  }
}
`, it returns id, key, raw, value and variableType.